# Skeleton Pattern with React and Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to implement a skeleton pattern into my ui. The stack involved is React -> Rebase -> Firebase.

The simplest (and probably the wrong...)way I found to achieve this pattern is a component that works like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Rebase from 're-base';
import {Placeholder, MyComponent} from 'somewhere';

class LazyDog extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
      isPending: false; //a boolean
    }
    this.checkPending = this.checkPending.bind(this);
  }

  checkPending(){
    if(!SomeRebaseData){
      this.setState(){
        isPending: true;
      }
    }else{
      this.setState(){
        isPending: false
      }
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.checkPending();
  }

  render() {
    if(!this.state.isPending){
    return (
      <Placeholder />
    )}else{
      <MyComponent />
    }
  }
}
```

It works but I don't feel this is the right way.
I am not aware of errors, it's inelegant but this works for now.
I would like to know if there is a better way to achieve this, maybe taking advantage of hoc and promises.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look at the [react-skeletor](https://github.com/trainline/react-skeletor) lib, it might help you a lot with this

Comment: Also, don't see any major problems in your code, I just think you could simplify it by removing those `if`'s... Not gonna write an answer as this is more of a tip, but change your `checkPending` function to `this.setState({isPending: !SomeRebaseData})` and your `render` function to `return(this.state.isPending ? <MyComponent /> : <Placeholder />)`... That should make your code much better

Comment: @AlexandreWiechersVaz Thank you for your comment. I will implement your tips asap.

Comment: Have you thought about using a Higher Order Component to pipe data within your child component so that it is re-usable.

Comment: This is exactly what i am asking for. Firebase is a realtime db, what I wrote in the example is an imperative construction: it suits well for a parent child composition. I think that a promise with an  async-await pattern is the right way to work. Until an answer I will study for a solution.